# Oracle how to convert time in UTC to the local time (offset information is missing)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which contains a date column. I think that the date in that column is saved in UTC.

I would like when the date is retrieved that it is printed in local time. That means when I call the date from Germany, the result should be something like this:

```
2015-04-29 11:24:06 +0200UTC EUROPE/BERLIN
```

I tried the following sql:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST(dateColum as  TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZR') from myTable;
```

the result looks like this:

```
2015-04-29 11:24:06 EUROPE/BERLIN
```

+/- offset is missing.

Any idea?

Comment: My first guess would be the format string needs something for the offset. This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588286/oracle-timestamp-with-timezone-named-zone-vs-offset

Comment: Found an older topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245250/oracle-casting-date-to-timestamp-with-time-zone-with-offset

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-07-13' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( value AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' )
           AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/BERLIN',
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM TZR'
       ) AS berlin_time
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
BERLIN_TIME
----------------------------------------
2016-07-13 02:00:00 +02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( value AS TIMESTAMP ), 'UTC' ) AT LOCAL,
         'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM TZR'
       ) AS local_time
FROM   table_name;
```

**Output**:

```
LOCAL_TIME
----------------------------------------
2016-07-13 02:00:00 +02:00 EUROPE/BERLIN
```

Comment: Thnak you. But the function should be static and can called from overall. It is not specific to be retrieved from EUROE

Comment: @Max_Salah Use `AT LOCAL` rather than `AT TIME ZONE ...`.

Comment: is it possible to conver to the local time even if the TIME zone is unknown? something like  FROM_TZ( CAST( value AS TIMESTAMP ), Server time zone...?

Comment: You could use `TO_CHAR( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'TZR' )` to get the system's time zone region and use that as the parameter for `FROM_TZ()`.

Comment: You can use TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ() instead of FROM_TZ(..., 'UTC') when you already have an ISO 8601 string (something like YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ).