# Subtracting hours from Unix Timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, unix-timestamp

The following query selects a unix timestamp. It should be 1pm but says 5pm because of UTC. It needs to be Eastern time 1pm, so I need to subtract 4 hours from it. What's the best way to go about this?

```
SELECT CAST(to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') + substr(STARTTIME,0,10)/60/60/24 as timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't caluclate manually. You should add or substract the timezone.

[Oracle how to convert time in UTC to the local time (offset information is missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346516/oracle-how-to-convert-time-in-utc-to-the-local-time-offset-information-is-missi)

Here an example-query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (
           FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
               AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/BERLIN',
           'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM TZR')
           AS BERLIN_Time_complete,
           TO_CHAR (
           FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
               AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
           'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM TZR')
           AS UTC_Complete,
           TO_CHAR (
           FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
               AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/BERLIN',
           'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS TZH:TZM')
           AS BERLIN_Time_complete,
           TO_CHAR (
           FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
               AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/BERLIN',
           'TZH:TZM')
           AS BERLIN_Timezone,
           TO_CHAR (
           FROM_TZ (CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC')
               AT TIME ZONE 'EUROPE/BERLIN',
           'TZR')
           AS Timezone_Name
  FROM DUAL;
```

The key is for Format:

- YYYY: Year with four digits (0000-9999 ex: 2018)
- MM: Month with two digits (01-12)
- DD: Day with two digits (01-31)
- HH24: Hour 00-23
- MI: Minutes 00-59
- SS: Seconds 00-59
- TZH: Timezone-Hours
- TZM: Timezone-Minutes (There are timezones with 30mins offset)
- TZR: Name of the timezone

You should play around with those, to understand the `to_date()`/`to_char()`. You'll need it.

If you realy want to add hours. Here an example:

```
select sysdate + INTERVAL '2' HOUR from dual;
```

Comment: @KaushikNayak Tanks! Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you, this link was very helpful. It's perfect except it returns the actual timezone too. Do you know how I can leave that out (the EUROPE/BERLIN text) of the result? Thanks!

Comment: Added an example-query and some explainaition for the pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS myDate
FROM   dual;
```

For more information read [this document](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-dates-timestamps-and-intervals).

Comment: This only selects the string o_O

Comment: He can change the pattern with the value he wants

Comment: He did not ask for a string. He wants to add 4 hours to his date.

Comment: he said _It should be 1pm but says 5pm because of UTC_ and _so I need to subtract 4 hours from it_  
Because his request does not return the good value. He asks for a good way of doing things. so it is not necessary to subtract 4 hours to have the good result.

Comment: But your solution `TO_CHAR()` does only return the wrong value as `string`/`varchar`. The some wrong value without any change.